# Sitefinity iFrame with dynamic height

Tags: iframe, sitefinity

How can I create an iFrame in Sitefinity which adapts its height dynamically to the content (in this case different forms for the user to fill out. Some are longer, some shorter).

I have a working solution on our current website (done with DotNetNuke), however, the exact same code does not work with Sitefinity. I does display the site correctly, but doesn't adapt to the size.

Any idea? Here my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

document.domain ="blvk.ch"

function resizeIframe(obj) 
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

window.onload = function() 
{
    var form = getQueryVariable("formular")
    var language = getQueryVariable("culture")
    var iframe = document.getElementById('formFrame');
iframe.src = "http://formular.blvk.ch/Webformulare_web/index.awp?P1=de-CH&P2=" + form;
}

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>TestText</p>
        <iframe name="Formular" id="formFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="Yes" style="width: 580px; height: 800px;" onload="resizeIframe(this)" seamless="seamless">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I should add that I'm no webdev at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`document.domain ="blvk.ch"` is setting the page to it's superdomain but the
iframe src is set to `'formular.blvk.ch'` which is why it is treated as a cross-domain iframe. You can read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Using `obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` for resizing is not going to work in this scenario. Assuming you have control over the both domains, you can use **iFrame-resizer** javascript library

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>iframe{width: 1px;min-width: 100%;}</style>
        <script>

document.domain ="blvk.ch"

function resizeIframe(obj) 
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

window.onload = function() 
{
    var form = getQueryVariable("formular")
    var language = getQueryVariable("culture")
    var iframe = document.getElementById('formFrame');
iframe.src = "http://formular.blvk.ch/Webformulare_web/index.awp?P1=de-CH&P2=" + form;
}

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>TestText</p>
        <iframe name="Formular" id="formFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless">
        </iframe>
        <script>iFrameResize({log:true}, '#formFrame')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```